# Can't get kaminari to show root node or meta data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

Rails 4.1.4
Ruby 2.2.0

What I want:

```
{
playlists: [
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "First MySQL Playlist",
    }
],
meta: {
    current_page: 1
}
```

}

What I'm getting:

```
[
{
    id: 2,
    name: "First MySQL Playlist",
}
```

]

I've done this many many many times before and have no idea why it's showing up like this. I've compared environments to previous projects, which work exactly how I want, and can't find any discrepancies. I'm hoping someone can spot something I'm missing.

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

gem 'active_model_serializers'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'kaminari'

Controller:

```
def index

    @playlists = Playlist.page(0).per(100)

    respond_with @playlists,
    root: :playlists,
    meta: {
      current_page: @playlists.current_page,
    }

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'mysql2','~> 0.3.18'
```